# Spray SSE with Akka 2.3.3 and Spray 1.3.1

Tags: angularjs, scala, server-sent-events, spray, scala-2.11

I'm using
Akka 2.3.3, Spray 1.3.1, scala 2.11.1 and AngularJS.

I'm looking for simple example of SSE comunication client-server for add new tweet (live) at my webpage.
I'm not using Play Framework.

I've already looked at this example but I have not figured out how to adapt it to my situation because the versions of the libraries are different: [**SIRIUX/SPRAY SSE**](https://github.com/siriux/spray_sse)

Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Http Chunking? You can have a long-living connection with Transfer-Encoding=chunked. Then consume twitter API on your web server and send each tweet (or group of tweets) as a chunk to the client. Spray has good support for Http chunking however it will be improved in Akka-Http